# find whether two tables have same rows in EXCEL

Tags: excel, windows-7, excel-2010, vlookup

I would like to find whether two tables have same rows in EXCEL.

e.g.

```
table1: 
 id1  value1  value2 
 358  5436     36464 
 2184  359     3646  

table2: 
 id1  value1  value2 
 358  5436     36464 
 21     109     9874
```

I need to lookup a row (from table2) in table1. So that it returns:

```
 id1  value1  value2 
 358  5436     36464
```

vlooup and index-match cannot help here.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Adding to +pnuts suggestion, you should use something like "=A2&B2&C2" as a formula in cell D2 for both tables, then you can simply use a VLOOKUP on column D from table 1 to see if it is in table 2 (if VLOOKUP is #N/A, then the row doesn't exist in table 2).  Then, you can do the same VLOOKUP from table 2 to see if it is in table 1.

Comment: @pnuts looks good.  do you want to put that as an answer so this question won't show up as Unanswered in SO?

Answer (score 0):

Another relatively simple way would require four steps, but simpler formulae (and, it's quicker when you have large tables):

1) Copy and paste both tables in another sheet, ONE UNDER ANOTHER (doesn't matter which goes first), the second one without the headers, like this:

```
table1: 
 id1  value1  value2 
 358  5436     36464 
 2184  359     3646  
 358  5436     36464 
 21     109     9874
```

2) Select the first cell of the table. On the ribbon "Data", select "Remove Duplicates".

A prompt will show listing all variables in your table (in this case, 'id 1', 'value 1', 'value 2').

Click on the button "Select all", then OK. This will make Excel filter every register where all variables match simultaneously.

Now there will be only duplicate rows left.

3) Back to the original Table 1, create a new header called "Duplicate check", then use the Match formula to search 'id 1' in Table 1 on the table without duplicates we already created. You will have something like this:

```
table1: 
 id1  value1  value2 Dup. check
 358  5436     36464    #N/A
 2184  359     3646        1
```

4) Filter the column Dup. check to show only the error records (#N/A or similar); copy the whole filtered range and paste it elsewhere AS A VALUE (Shortcut: ALT + C V V). Now clear all data in the Duplicate Check column, and you have a table with duplicate IDs only!

Hope it helps!